# Expectation of product of two random variables (no assumption)

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

What is the relation between the expectation of product of two random variables ($E[XY]$) and their conditional expectation ($E[X|Y]$)? No assumption is being made regarding any variable or the relation between the variables.

Consider the following derivation for discrete case (continuous case will be similar):

\begin{align*}
E[XY]
&= \sum_{x,y} x y P(X=x, Y=y)\\
&= \sum_{x,y} x y P(X=x|Y=y) P(Y=y)\\
&= \sum_{y} y \sum_{x} x P(X=x|Y=y) P(Y=y)\\
&= \sum_{y} y E[X|Y=y] P(Y=y)\\
&= E[YE[X|Y]] \\
&= E[Y]E[X|Y]
\end{align*}

Please point out if there is an error. Thanks!

Comment: What you have done only works if you know that $|X|, |Y|$ are convergent because you use that you can interchange the sums or if you interpret discrete as only meaning finite

Comment: When $X=Y$, your derivation ends up as $E(Y)^2$, not $E(Y^2)$, which is what it should be.

Comment: $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable, so you cannot split $E[YE[X|Y]]$ into the product $E[Y]E[X|Y]$ in general. For instance, if $X=Y$, then $E[X|Y]=Y$.

Comment: @SangchulLee So is there a way to simplify the sum over y above? Or is that the simplest form

Comment: Without further information, $E[XY]=E[YE[X|Y]]$ is the best one can hope for. This is because $E[X|Y=y]$ can assume any function of $y$ provided all the related expectations exist.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for your comments. This expression $\displaystyle\sum_{y} y E[X|Y=y] P(Y=y)$ is of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{y} g(y) P(Y=y)$ where $g(y) = yE[X|Y=y]$ is a function of $y$. After summing over $y$, the result should be independent of $y$, isn't it?